# What are the names of graphs with $2$ in/outbound edges?

Tags: terminology, graph-theory

I know that many types graphs have unique names, ie. a directed graph where each node has exactly one outbound edge is known as a *functional* graph. Do the graphs with exactly $2$ inbound/outbound edges have a name?

**Bonus**: If the $2$ inbound/outbound graph is named, is the $n$th inbound/outbound graph named?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as a $d$-regular graph (at least if the graph is undirected). If your graph is a sub-graph of a bigger graph, then it is a $d$-factor. Finally, for $d=2$ it's also called a *cycle cover*, since it's a collection of cycles (if it's finite). For $d=1$ it's called a *matching*. For $d=3$ it is known as a *cubic graph*.

For directed graphs it's usually not clear what is supposed to be regular, the in-degree, the out-degree or both.